# Display only the Positive Y side of chart Control in windows Form .net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-chart-controls

I've Created a Chart Control and made a Forecast on Series which I inputed for it
The forecast is on products demands
all is well except that it also displayes forecast to a negative demand
Can I dusable negetive forecast?
Or better can I display only the Positive Y side Of the Chart?

Thank you

*attached the codebinding and forecast code

```
`Demand_Chart.DataBindCrossTable(reader, "Product", "Year", "Quantity", "Label=Quantity");                 Demand_Chart.DataManipulator.FinancialFormula(System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.FinancialFormula.Forecasting,"Exponential," + Forecat_Delta + ",true,true", Prod + ":Y", "Forecast:Y,UB:Y,LB:Y");`
```